# Rails isn't returning from this action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The problem I have is very simple. Basically, I have a Rails action for my videos page. It makes a HTTP request and gets some response back. But I am trying to add error checking right now. My problem is it will NOT LEAVE this action after entering the `if` block. It appears to continue to try to run all the code after the `if` block... Which is bad because if it enters the `if` block, it means we didn't get a 200 OK response. There's nothing to run. Just throw an error message and yeet!

It is entering the `if` block ([Gyazo link here](https://gyazo.com/2086e1b4974d8e4194fc6ac3dc7a9e20)).

```
  def videos
    # get current_user's wistia_project_id & authorization token
    @current_user = current_user
    project_id = @current_user.wistia_project_id
    auth_token = "blah"
    request = "https://api.wistia.com/v1/projects/#{project_id}.json?api_password=#{auth_token}"

    @response = HTTP.get(request)

    puts "BEFORE"

    # handle errors (4xx & 5xx)
    # catches client errors and server errors
    # should print out and then LEAVE this entire action. (return)
    if @response.status.client_error? || @response.status.server_error?
      puts "INSIDE"
      render text: "Sorry, error"
      return
    end

    @response = HTTP.get(request).body
    # get embed code for each video using the hashed_id, put in list
    # BUT!!! for some reason it gets here and there's an error 
    # because there is nothing in the response (errors) 
    @video_iframe_urls = JSON.parse(@response)['medias'].map do |p|
      "https://fast.wistia.com/embed/iframe/#{p["hashed_id"]}?version=v1&controlsVisibleOnLoad=true&playerColor=aae3d8"
    end
  end
```

Comment: That error does not show that it is "not returning" it shows that `@video_iframe_urls` is unset so actual what is showing is that it is returning however `render text:` is [no longer supported](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-removals) try `render plain: 'Sorry, error'` instead.

Comment: Please, add the error to the question itself. It is [bad idea to post code/errors as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9269043), especially as a link to image. It is not the first time the community asks about it, please make your questions convenient for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render text: "Sorry, error"
```

change this line to plain

```
render plain: "Sorry, error"
```

the problem is not

> it will NOT LEAVE this action after entering the if block.

because render is not support text options.you code actually is

```
    if @response.status.client_error? || @response.status.server_error?
      puts "INSIDE"
      render
      return
    end
```

the render method render template name by action name as default